# Alfresco on the web

Tags: distributed, alfresco

I am searching for some information about using Alfresco as a web only system. I am interested to know if it is possible to install Alfresco on some web hosting server, so that we dont need to install it on any of our system. The objective is to get all the functionalities Alfresco is providing, but without installing any software on the system. So that it can be accessed from anywhere. The team is geographically distributed and we need to collaborate.

I think there is some solution out there but could not find by simply going through the forums, and searching in google.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alfresco is installable anywhere. 
You just need a server to install it on. Why not a hosting server?
So - either get a dedicated server somewhere, maybe a VPS or a cloud.
Maybe you can even rent a java hosting somewhere and deploy alfresco on some shared tomcat?

This also depends on what you plan to do with alfresco - do you plan to just use out of the box features or do you want to customize it a lot? How many users will be using alfresco, how intensively?

First get some draft on that and then you'll know.

Comment: Thanks for that info. We are just three right now and we only need to use it for document authoring and versioning. The normal usage will be like: One person will create and upload the files and notify the other two members. The other two members will go and give their comments on the document. Based on those comments, the first member then make a revision of that document and upload it again and the cycle continues. The important thing for me to know is if we install alfresco on web (any free or paid server), do we still need to install anything on the client systems accessing the documents.

Comment: Most likely not. The only thing you *might* need is imagemagick for conversions. Optionally swftools (for pdf preview) within the app itself. Also - for just three users and the scenario you described - alfresco is great, everything should work out of the box.

Comment: It appears that we can install it on some demo java based hosting facility (like www.eatj.com) they provide Tomcat, MySql and JDK 1.6. Now the question is that is there any simple installer to install alfresco like we have for the windows based installation.

Comment: Hmm. You either grab the bundle install package, or 1. create the database, 2.deploy alfresco.war and share.war (and mobile.war, but I never used that one )